# Deploy a web application that depends on standalone application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, wiremock

I have a web application (JSF), which uses two web services (REST). Pending the achievement of these web services, I use mocks (WIREMOCK).
By deploying the application, I have to start both mocks calling main methods.
Is there a way to group these three tasks in one task (maven plugin or other)?

1. Run tomcat
2. Call main method for mock server 1
3. Call main method for mock server 2

Comment: Try with exec maven plugin:  http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but it is not generic because it related to the eclipse environment. It consists of using the `launcher Composite` eclipse plugin.